# Node JS redirection loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect, routes

I have this chunk of code:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect(301, 'http://example.com' + req.path);
});
```

and chrome writes error:

"The example.com page isn’t working

example.com redirected you too many times."

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do expect it to stop redirecting?

Comment: Is `http://example.com` in your example the hostname of your server? In other words: are you redirecting to your own server?

Comment: It looks like infinite loop...

Comment: Goal is to redirect from www.example.com to example.com or from example.net to example.com

Comment: Then make the redirect conditional based on the host.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your code always redirects you.

You need to add a host checker condition.

For example:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
   if (/^www\./.test(req.headers.host)) {
     res.redirect(301, 'http://example.com' + req.path);
   }
});
```